# Laravel migrations - foreign key not applying to the table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

I have tried add foreign key constraint using migrations. The migration completes without any error. However, when the database is checked, the foreign key constraint is not added to the table. Other things specified in the migrations work fine except of FK constraint.

My pivot table with FKs:

```
Schema::create('book_author', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->integer('book_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('author_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('book_id')->references('id')->on('book')->onDelete('restrict')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('author')->onDelete('restrict')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->primary(['book_id','author_id']);

        });
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

Author table:

```
Schema::create('author', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('email', 250)->unique();
        });
```

Book table:

```
 Schema::create('book', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
        });
```

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Which database?  How are you checking to make sure the foreign key is there?

Comment: By adding a field with bogus 'id' values for both columns.

Comment: Is your table engine InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: Have you tried making the changes I suggested in my answer? If so is the problem still there?

Comment: Yes. Same result. No difference. BTW I didn't down vote your answer.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I didn't change the default engine. Therefore, I think its MyISAM.

Comment: MyISAM doesn't support foreign keys. Please, run `SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'book_author'` and check which engine your table has.

Comment: Ah... Such a shame... Np thanks for the info, it's always strange when people downvote without commenting. I'll leave my answer here in case somebody else finds it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyISAM doesn't support foreign key: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html

Run the following command to make sure which engine your table has:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'book_author'
```

If it shows `MyISAM`, you have two option:

1. don't use FK at all
2. Replace your engine

I would go with option 2, because you are creating a new table and there is no risk to lose data here.

You can force in your migrations with:

```
$table->engine = 'InnoDB';
```

Alternatively, you can run this command manually:

```
ALTER TABLE book_author ENGINE=INNODB
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your **book_author** migration to:

```
Schema::create('book_author', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('book_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->integer('author_id')->unsigned()->index();

    $table->foreign('book_id')->references('id')->on('book')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('author')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
});
```

This should work.

---

On the other note you're breaking a few Laravel conventions with your table names:

1. Name your tables in plural form (**authors** & **books**)
2. The pivot table (**book_author**) should be called (**author_book**) - *alphabetical priority*.